# how to add a scene to a previously defined QGraphicsView

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a predefined GUI that is loaded in as a .ui file:

```
def __init__(self):
    # Initialise main program with GUI
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('fg_control_gui_2.ui', self)
```

inside that ui file I have defined a QGraphicsView, that looks as follows in the .py version of the GUI:

```
    self.ch1_oszi_view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
    self.ch1_oszi_view.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 450, 361, 261))
    self.ch1_oszi_view.setObjectName("ch1_oszi_view")
```

Now I want to add a QGraphicsScene as a canvas so I can show a plot in my GUI which is supposed to be done like this:

```
scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)
```

My Question is now, how can I hand the scene to the previously defined QGraphicsView like it is done in the second line of code of my last example ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`setScene()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#setScene) method of [`QGraphicsView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html):

```py
scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
self.ch1_oszi_view.setScene(scene)
```

Comment: @darmstadtbeste please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: I did that, what is wrong with my question?